# Android - Drawing on thread

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview

I want to draw something repetitivelely each 100 milliseconds or when a button is pressed. For the button onclick event it works right, but I can't make it work in a thread. Following is the code:

onclick

```
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Draw();
        }
    });
```

thread

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
{

    public void run()
    {
        Draw();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

Draw method

```
private void Draw(){

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int i;

    Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

    // Dibujo el fondo
    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), paint);

    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the UI thread runs separately to your `Runnable` thread. Separate threads like this cannot interact. You will need to use an `AsyncTask` thread which will enable you to periodically access the UI thread.

For example:

```
private class ExampleThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         while(!isCancelled()) { // Keep going until cancelled
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(100); // Delay 100 milliseconds
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 Thread.interrupted();
             }
             publishProgress(); // Run onProgressUpdate() method
             if(isCancelled()) break; // Escape early if cancel() is called
         }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void... params) {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... params) {
        // Here you can access the UI thread
        Draw();
    }
}
```

To start the thread:

```
ExampleThread thread = new ExampleThread();
thread.execute();
```

To stop the thread:

```
thread.cancel();
```

More information and examples with AsyncTask can be found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example).